# Symfony2 Generate SQL logs for specific functions in my controller

Tags: php, symfony, logging

I have some functions which are used to insert and update database tables in my Symfony2 project. For those functions I want to generate a verbose SQL log for all insert and update queries which are being executed with their result.

I have tried to do it manually but I am unable to get the SQL queries from the object that is persist and Flushed.

Here is my controller function:

```
private function pushChapterToCdpCodes($testObjectEntity, $testReleaseId) {

    $chapterTitle = $testObjectEntity->getTitle();
    $chapterNumber = $testObjectEntity->getNumber();
    $chapterOriginalId = $testObjectEntity->getOriginalId();
    // update chapter table

    if ($chapterOriginalId) {
        $chapter = $this->chapterRepository->findOneBy(array('id' => $chapterOriginalId));
    } else {
        $bookTitle = $testObjectEntity->getBook()->getTitle();
        $bookObject = $this->bookRepository->findOneBy(array('title' => $bookTitle));
        $bookId = $bookObject->getId();
        $bookPart = $testObjectEntity->getBookPart();
        $chapter = new \ICC\BookBundle\Entity\Chapter();

        if ($bookPart) {
            $bookPartOriginalNumber = $testObjectEntity->getBookPart()->getNumber();
            $bookPartOriginalTitle = $testObjectEntity->getBookPart()->getTitle();
            $originalBookPart = $this->bookPartRepository->findOneBy(array('number' => $bookPartOriginalNumber, 'title' => $bookPartOriginalTitle));
            $chapter->setBookPart($originalBookPart);
        } else {
            $chapter->setBook($this->bookRepository->findOneBy(array('id' => $bookId)));
        }
    }

    $chapter->setTitle($chapterTitle);
    $chapter->setNumber($chapterNumber);
    $chapter->setErrataReleaseId($testReleaseId);
    $this->cdpCodesEm->persist($chapter);
    $this->cdpCodesEm->flush();
}
```

I need the SQL log for the above `$this->cdpCodesEm->persist($chapter);` result.

Please help me what is the right way to do this.

Comment: If any one can tell how to get the SQL query from that $this->cdpCodesEm->persist($chapter); object, That will be appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Comment: have you already see this article? http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/logging-doctrine-queries-in-symfony2/

Comment: Thanks @Matteo It works for me .. :)

Comment: @Matteo  I have read your blog
http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/logging-doctrine-queries-in-symfony2/
I have used the DebugStack logger to log all the queries in a file. But I also need the output (Success or Failure) of the logged queries. Is it possible to get it ?
Please help me out of it.